# How to handle python raw_input() in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I created a batch file to run files in sequence, however my python file takes in an input (from calling raw_input), and I am trying to figure out how to handle this over the batch file.

**run.bat**

*The program doesn't proceed to the next line after the .py file is executed, for brevity i just just showed necessary commands*

```
cd C:\Users\myname\Desktop
python myfile.py
stop
```

**myfile.py**

```
print ("Enter environment (dev | qa | prod) or stop to STOP")
environment = raw_input()
```

Comment: Change `raw_input()` to `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: @jordanm I think OP wants to take input from standard input, not arguments.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Not according to his `run.bat` example.

Comment: @jordanm OP does not have any arguments for myfile.py

Comment: Im sorry im new to python what does OP mean?

Comment: @teddybear123 Original poster :) Not a python terminology.

Comment: it means ... you :) (I thought: owner of the post but it's not even that!)

Comment: the idea is to run myfile.py multiple times and take in arguments (dev, qa and prod) in sequence

Comment: maybe you mean `echo stop|python myfile.py` (output redirection through a pipe). You'd be better off with arguments as @jordanm first suggested.

Comment: let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

Take your myfile.py file, and change it to the following:

```
import sys

def main(arg = None):
    # Put all of your original myfile.py code here
    # You could also use raw_input for a fallback, if no arg is provided:
    if arg is None:
        arg = raw_input()
    # Keep going with the rest of your script

# if __name__ == "__main__" ensures this code doesn't run on import statements
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #arg = sys.argv[1] allows you to run this myfile.py directly 1 time, with the first command line paramater, if you want

    if len(sys.argv) > 0:
        arg = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        arg = None

    main(arg)
```

Then create another python file, called wrapper.py:

```
#importing myfile here allows you to use it has its own self contained module
import sys, myfile

# this loop loops through the command line params starting at index 1 (index 0 is the name of the script itself)
for arg in sys.argv[1 : ]:

    myfile.main(arg)
```

And then at the command line, you can simply type:

```
python wrapper.py dev qa prod
```

You could also put the above line of code in your run.bat file, making it look at follows:

```
cd C:\Users\myname\Desktop
python wrapper.py dev qa prod
stop
```

Answer (score -1):

the question is not related to python. To your shell. According http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html cmd.exe uses the same syntax as unix shell (cmd1 | cmd2), so your bat file should work fine when called with command, which will send the file content to standard output.

Edit: added example

```
echo "dev" | run.bat
C:\Python27\python.exe myfile.py
Enter environment (dev | qa | prod) or stop to STOP
environment="dev"
```

Comment: I have slighly changed the python script to print the environment variable.

    echo "dev" | run.bat
    C:\Python27\python.exe myfile.py
    Enter environment (dev | qa | prod) or stop to STOP
    environment="dev"